# How to show hidden files (dotfiles) with windows powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, dotfiles

When I have hidden files, like *dotfiles* or a `.git` directory: 
How can I list those files and directories in Powershell?

Neither `Get-ChildItem`, `dir` nor `ls` seem to show them.

Comment: Dotfiles are not hidden in Windows. The convention in Unix world is that, say, `ls` doesn't show those per default. In Windows, file attributes are used instead. These can be modified with `attrib.exe` or via Explorer, when its configured to show hidden items.

Comment: You can alter the attributes without resorting to any other utility in powershell: `(Get-ChildItem SomeFile.txt).Attributes = 'Hidden'`

Comment: @vonPryz in my FileExplorer > View, I have set "show hidden files". But it is still not listed when using gci/dir/ls.

Comment: Up to you really. Personally I prefer to delete dupes but it isn't a huge deal as far as I know.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In order to show such hidden files, use the `-Force` parameter for the `Get-Childitem` command.

```
Get-ChildItem . -Force
```

You also can use its aliases, with `-Force`

```
dir -Force
ls -Force
gci -Force
```

Also: if you want to delete fully delete e.g. the *.git Directory*, you may use `Delete-Item .\.git -Force`

According to `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Examples` "Example 3" this also works:
`dir -att h, !h`

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Attributes Hidden, !Hidden` if you like to type

Comment: "ls -at h " would be the shortest

Comment: -force and -FORCE do work too.

Comment: you can also do
`dir -Fo`
`ls -Fo`
`gci -Fo`

Comment: Thanks, man. @ricardoNava. This obviously made it much simpler.