# What is the terminal command to view hidden folders in a git repo on VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, hidden-files

I am attempting to view my .git directory on VSCode by entering the command to show hidden files. I understand that on a Mac, this command is: la

I've read that on Windows, the equivalent command is: ls -la

However, after entering this to the VSCode terminal I am faced with the following error:

[image: Error which appears]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `la` is just an alias for `ls -la` on some systems.  `ls -la` will work under Git Bash on Windows or on any Unix system (including WSL).  Your problem is that you're trying to use PowerShell instead of Git Bash.

Comment: look at this question [How to show hidden files (dotfiles) with windows powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817139/how-to-show-hidden-files-dotfiles-with-windows-powershell)

Comment: You can change the default terinal from powerhell to git-bash by following along the answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal. Then the 'ls -la' command should work.

Answer (score 2):

@siddart:
You are unfortunately incorrect on how you show hidden (dotfiles) files in the terminal/command line on macOS. In order to access hidden files/folders on macOS it is actually `ls` and if you want to find hidden files/folders on macOS, then you use: `$ ls -a`

Next, you are referring to *PowerShell* as compared to just the Command Prompt. `cmd`

**Be aware:** There is a difference in the commands and arguments in Powershell as compared to the Command Prompt.

So with that all taken care of, the actual way to do it in Windows via Command Prompt should be exactly the same as it should be in the VS Code terminal.

The folks over at Minitool show [4 different ways to show hidden files](https://www.minitool.com/news/show-hidden-files-windows-10.html) from their example, I'll only show you the one from the CMD Prompt.

---

> ## How to Show Hidden Files Windows 10 with CMD
>
> You can open Command Prompt in Windows 10 to show hidden files with `attrib` command.
>
> ### Detailed steps are as follows:
>
> - **Step 1.** Press *Windows + R*, type `cmd`, and press *Ctrl + Shift + Enter* to open elevated Command Prompt in your Windows 10 computer.
> - **Step 2.** Then you can type this command line: `attrib -h -r -s /s /d E:\*.*`, and hit *Enter* to unhide the files and folders in drive **E**. You should replace the drive letter with the exact drive letter of your computer. You can open This PC to check the drive letters of your computer hard drive partitions.

---

```
C:\Windows\system32>attrib -h -r -s /s /d E:\*.*
```

---

### Show hidden files cmd

To help you better understand this `attrib` command, below is the explanation of each part of the command line.

- `–h`: It clears the Hidden file attribute to show hidden files.
- `–r`: It clears the Read-only file attribute to allow you modify the file after it shows.
- `–s`: It clears the System file attribute.
- `/s`: It applies `attrib` and any command-line options to matching files in the current directory and all of its subdirectories.
- `/d`: It applies `attrib` and any command-line options to directories.

---

@Siddart I hope that answers your question.

[git](/questions/tagged/git) [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) [hidden-files](/questions/tagged/hidden-files) [commamd-prompt](/questions/tagged/commamd-prompt) [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal) [attrib-command](/questions/tagged/attrib-command) [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

Comment: This does not show hidden files but unhides the files

Answer (score 1):

When in the Powershell on Windows you must use dir -force to show all files including hidden git files. dir is the command to show your normal files and dir -force shows all.

Answer (score 0):

Either use

`Get_ChildItem . -Force`

or use

```
ls -Force
```

It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the shell. If you are in `cmd`, you would want to use

```
dir /a
```

to see all files and folders including the hidden items.